# how to handle accessibility issues related with OUTLOOK

Tags: c#, outlook

I've a situation,my software's folder is shared on network and user can execute application on his system as his own.The problem is while he is trying to send mails through OUTLOOK using the application.following exception is thrown

"Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {0006F03A-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80080005 Server execution failed (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80080005 (CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE))."

I searched internet whole day and found it is accessibility issues of processes making the problem.I tried with regedit as suggested by msdn,but unfortunately it is also not helpful.Is there any solution for this can be done programatically.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens if the security contexts of your app and Outlook are different. Is either one running with elevated privileges (Run As administrator)?

Comment: Exactly,Is there any way to solve it programatically ?

Comment: No, if the security contexts are different, the COM system will not let you talk to a COM object from another process. This is a security feature.